# How do I get the text before the character clicked on?

Tags: javascript, string, str-replace

I want to get the text before the character '/' from the string. It is repeating itself many times in my string and hence not able to get its index. So, how do I get the text before it? For example string "C:/users/username/desktop/lib" and if I click on the slash before username it should show "C:/users".

I have already tried `indexOf()` and `CharAt()` functions but in vain as they aren't appropriate to the problem.

Please try to provide the answer in JavaScript and not JQuery.

Comment: You can't "click" in javascript, as Javascript lacks a UI. I would guess there's an html component to the question which you've omitted, making your question impossible to answer without wild guesswork.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to do something like this...

```js
    let el = document.querySelector('p'),
    text = el['innerText'],
    characters = text.split('');
    el.innerHTML = '';

    characters.forEach(char => {
        let span = document.createElement('span');
        span.innerText = char;
        span.addEventListener('click', onClick);
        el.appendChild(span);
    });

    function onClick() {
        let position = 0,
            el = this;

        while (el.previousSibling !== null) {
            position++;
            el = el.previousSibling;
        }

        let newText = text.substring(0, position);
        console.log(newText.substring(0, newText.lastIndexOf('/')));
    }
```

```html
<p>C:/users/username/desktop/lib</p>
```

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I wanted to do!

Answer (score 0):

I tried do something like this

```
<div class="display">
</div>
```

```
const display = document.querySelector(".display");
const begin = "C:/users/username/desktop/lib"
display.textContent= begin
display.addEventListener("click", getSelectionPosition, false); 

let bool = false
function getSelectionPosition () {
 if(bool == false){
  var selection = window.getSelection();
 const index = selection.focusOffset;
   console.log(display.textContent[index]);
 if(display.textContent[index] == "/"){
   display.textContent = display.textContent.substring(0, index);
 } 
 else if(display.textContent[index-1] == "/"){
      display.textContent = display.textContent.substring(0, index-1);
 }
   else if(display.textContent[index+1] == "/"){
  display.textContent = display.textContent.substring(0, index+1);
 }
}
else{
   display.textContent = begin;
}
  bool = !bool;
}
```